# Close UIWebView, when javascript issues "window.close"

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which renders a javascript. I want to kill this UIWebView whenever the javascript rendered in the UIWebView is closed.

In essence, I want to have the UIWebView only for loading the javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute javascript you do not need to add uiwebview on current views. You can execute wathever you want without displaying your uiwebview onto the screen.

To notify your uiwebview to close itself use javascript. First you have to set your class as delegate of your uiwebview:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myWebWithJavascript.html"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
//if your are not to display webview, frame dimensions does not mind
UIWebView uiwebview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 480)];
[uiwebview setDelegate:self];  //remember that your .h has to implement <UIWebViewDelegate> 
[uiwebview loadRequest:request];

//then you implement notifications:
//this is executed when uiwebview has been loaded
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{ 
   //put here code if you wanna do something with uiwebview once has finished loading 
}
//this one is executed if your request returns any error on loading page
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
//put here code if you wanna manage html errors
}
//this one it the ONE you will use to receive messages from javascript code:
//this function is executed every time an http request is made
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { 
        //we check every time there is an http request if the request contains
        //an special prefix that indicates it is not a real http request, but 
        //a comunication from javascript code 
        if ([[[req URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"my-special-frame"]) {
             //so thats it- javascript code is indicating me to do something
             //for example: closing uiwebview:
             [webview release];  //probably it would be cleverer not to kill this way your uiwebview...but it is just an example
             return NO; //that is important because avoid uiwebview to load this fake http request 
        }   
 return YES; //that means that it will load http request that skips the if clause   
}
```

Then in your javascript you just need to make an http request with that special prefix we are expecting on objective-c code:

```
   var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
   iframe.setAttribute("src", "my-special-frame:uzObjectiveCFunction");
   document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
```

In this example I open a frame with a URL that contains our special prefix. You could also make a simple:

```
   document.location.href = my-special-frame:uzObjectiveCFunction;
```

Hope this help your doubts! Good luck!